# T-SQL count like string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is the select statement that I'm trying to use, and I'm trying to pull the count of all records that start with the phrase Unknown, but I'm getting an incorrect syntax error near the closing parenthesis of the count. How can I use count in this way?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [ID], COUNT(ID), COUNT([NAME] LIKE 'Unknown%')
FROM table.foo
GROUP BY [ID]
```

Comment: Put the condition in a `Where` clause.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `SELECT DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`.  Just use a `CASE` as the argument to `SUM()`:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(ID), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN NAME LIKE 'Unknown%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table.foo
GROUP BY ID;
```